# Cannot install Chrome or Google Drive on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (P1000)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I tried to install Chrome or Google Drive on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 4.0.4) but the app page in Google Play says "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

Can I install an older version? Or is there any workaround.

I updated my system.

*Later update:* Any other application that I tried to install was giving `Error retrieving information from server. [RPC:...]`

Comment: I can't figure out what the issue could be, but to install older version you can try searching the apk on the internet. There are sites like https://www.apkmirror.com that collect the apk of a lot of apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do to solve this was

1. Go to `Settings > Accounts`
2. Remove the Google account
3. Add back the Google account
4. Go to `Settings > Applications > All`
5. Clear data for applications 'Google Play Services`,`Google Play Store` (basically any system service or application from Google that had to do anything with Play Store)
6. Reboot the tablet

Now I can install applications, including Drive and Chrome.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have a galaxy 10.1 P-GT7510 running Android 4.0.4